# Returning differences between two columns in two different files in excel using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, concatenation, difference

I have two csv files with a common column named 'Name'. File 2 will continuously update and add new values randomly in the column. How can i write a script to compare the two columns and find the differences regardless of where the new values are placed in file2.

Other solutions will find the differences only if the new values are at the end of the column, not randomly within the column.

Code I have tried (only outputs the new values at the bottom of the column, not when it is randomly in the column):

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')

new_df = (df1[['Name']].merge(df2[['Name']],on='Name',how = 'outer',indicator = True)
                       .query("_merge != 'both'")
                       .drop('_merge',axis = 1))

new_df.to_csv('file4.csv')
```

File1:

```
Name     
gfd454
3v4fd
th678iy
```

File2:

```
Name     
gfd454
fght45
3v4fd
th678iy
```

The output should be:

```
Name
fght45
```

Comment: Please provide sample input and output to make a [mcve]

Comment: @G.Anderson done

Comment: Please use the question you opened previously for any clarifications rather than opening a duplicate

Comment: @G.Anderson unfortunately it does not. those options will find the differences only if they are added at the end of the column, but these values add at random so if it is added randomly in the column and not the end, it will not detect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# df1 original dataframe of File_1 data
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':[ 'gfd454' , '3v4fd', 'th678iy']})

# df2 dataframe of changing File_2 data
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':[ 'gfd454' , 'abcde', 'fght45', '3v4fd', 'abcde' ,'th678iy', 'abcde']})

# Assuming df1 comprises distinct elements and doesn't change, and that
# df2 contains all elements of df1 and more (the new updates) 
# df2 may have duplicates like 'abcde'

# Drop duplicates in df2, if df1 has duplicates also drop it first
# ``keep = first`` : Drop duplicates except for the first occurrence.
df2.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=True)
print(df2)

# pandas.concat adds elements of df2 to df1, even if it already exists in df1
df_concat = pd.concat([df1,df2], join='outer', ignore_index = True)
print(df_concat)
```

[image: df_concat]

```
# now drop the duplicates between df1, df2
df_diff = df_concat .drop_duplicates(keep=False)
print(df_diff)
```

[image: df_diff]

Now, the problem with this is that you have to ensure that df1-df2 = {},
i.e. df1 is subset of df2

Comment: how would you print the differences to verify it worked?

Comment: it only detects the different values if they are at the end of the column. i have a value randomly placed in one of the columns and it wont detect it

Comment: can you better explain this code to me? i input it the same way you did and it doesn't work

Comment: If you have other columns, then you have to groupby 'Name' first

Comment: you could also try 'inner' join instead of outer, or df1.set_index('Name'), or give me better example of your files and what exactly you expect

Answer (score 0):

Do a left join, using File 2 on the left. After, extract the NaN lines that don't match.

Comment: can you write this into a script so i can get better sense of it?

Comment: I thought better and I 've found better solution for you:
`dfDiff = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 0).drop_duplicates(keep = False)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check only on one column you can try it by comparing two lists:

```
list1=df1['Name'].tolist()
list2=df2['Name'].tolist()
s = set(list1)
diff = [x for x in list2 if x not in s]
```

Comment: i am only getting the differences between columns when the different values are at the end of the column. I have a value randomly placed in the file2 column and it does not detect it.